# Read Text File, Update Fields C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, import, config

I am trying to basically create config files. A text file will hold something like:

```
Name::Adam
Location::Washington
```

I am trying to grab the first part as the field name (i.e. `Name.Text` would update the `TextBox`) then put the second part to that `Text`.  Just not sure where to go or what the best way to build this is.  The code below is incomplete because I can't figure out how to update the textboxes.

Thanks for the help!

```
private void clickImportConfig_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
   Stream myStream = null;
   string fieldUpdate = string.Empty;
   string fieldUpdateTo = string.Empty;

   try
   {
      using (myStream)
      {
         string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\\config.txt");
         foreach (string s in lines)
         {
            var splitted = Regex.Split(s, "::");
            fieldUpdate = splitted[0].ToString();
            fieldUpdateTo = splitted[1].ToString();

         }
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
private void clickImportConfig_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream = null;
    string fieldUpdate = string.Empty;
    string fieldUpdateTo = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        using (myStream)
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\\config.txt");
            foreach (string s in lines)
            {
                string[] splitted = s.Split(new string[] { "::" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                fieldUpdate = splitted[0].ToString();
                fieldUpdateTo = splitted[1].ToString();

                // TextBox textBox = (TextBox)this.FindName(fieldUpdate);
                // Or
                    TextBox textBox = this.FindName(fieldUpdate) as TextBox;
                // See below for an explanation
                if (textBox != null) // FindName returns null if nothing is found with that name
                {
                    textBox.Text = fieldUpdateTo;
                }
             }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

As insane_developer pointed out, you will be better off using the `String.Split` method (`s` being the string in this case so written as `s.Split()`) instead of `Regex.Split`. It will give you the benefit of removing any empty results from the array. It may also have better performance as Regex is capable of a lot more complicated things, but I haven't tested that so I could be wrong.

You can use the `FindName(string name)` method to find an element with the specified name. This method returns `null` if nothing is found and an `object` if the element is found. This `object` will need to be cast to the type you are expecting (I.e. `TextBox`). You can do this in one of the following ways:

```
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)this.FindName(fieldUpdate);
```

or

```
TextBox textBox = this.FindName(fieldUpdate) as TextBox;
```

The first option will throw an `InvalidCastException` if `FindName` returns an object which is not a `TextBox`. The second option will instead just set the value of `textBox` to null which will be checked by the `if` statement and the exception will be avoided. As you are only catching all generic exceptions in this code, an `InvalidCastException` would show your "Could not read file from disk" message which is not true. So you may want to add an additional catch block to handle any invalid casting.

If you're wondering why you don't just stick to the second option as it solves this problem, then consider this scenario as an example. Lets say in the future you decide for some reason that you want to change all of your `TextBox` to `TextBlock` or something else, but forget to come back to change this code, or accidently end up with the name of another type of control in your text file. The second option will set the value of `textBox` to `null` and your field(s) won't be updated. But there will be absolutely no errors, leaving you scratching your head and having to debug the problem. The first option would throw an `InvalidCastException` showing you exactly where the problem is. You could then choose how to handle this problem by either showing another message box or silently writing the error to a log file etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression, just:

```
var splitted = s.Split("::", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
fieldUpdate = splitted[0];
fieldUpdateTo = splitted[1];
```

For the rest you have to be more explicit

Comment: Thanks.  For the rest I have textboxes.  Like fullName (fullName.Text) and userLocation (userLocation.Text).  Ideally what I would do is take the info from the split string then update the corresponding textbox with the info.  so if fieldUpdate turns out to be "fullName" from the split and fieldUpdateTo is "Adam" then it should be similar to fullName.Text = "Adam";